# How to install libstoragemgmt on ubuntu 20.04 server?

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install `libstoragemgmt` using

`apt-get install - y libstoragemgmt-tools`

But I got  this error `unable to locate this package`

On man page I found that there are two prerequisites  lsmd daemon and URI
so for lsmd I installed `daemontools` - which i didn't know if that was what it needed or not - but i can't know how to deal with uri or what i missed -

Comment: Please copy & paste actual commands & output into your question, the package `libstoragemgmt` isn't available for *focal* or 20.04 that I can see; so where did you get it from? Why are you using the `-y` option if you haven't sorted out issues beforehand? (the `-y` is used if you've verified the issues & want to proceed without being pestered by 'are you sure?' type questions; yet clearly you weren't at that stage).

Answer (score 3):

This package were [last available in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://repology.org/project/libstoragemgmt/versions).

The [ArchLinux's AUR page](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libstoragemgmt) mentions https://github.com/libstorage/libstoragemgmt URL as upstream.

So you have to build this package locally by using commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev git pkg-config autoconf automake bash-completion build-essential check chrpath debhelper devscripts dh-autoreconf dh-python dh-systemd file g++ gcc libconfig-dev libglib2.0-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libtool libtool-bin libudev-dev libxml2-dev lintian make perl procps python3-dev python3-six systemd tar valgrind

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/libstorage/libstoragemgmt -b 1.9.3
cd libstoragemgmt
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -b
sudo apt-get install ../*libstoragemgmt*.deb
```

Also you can find details on  https://libstorage.github.io/libstoragemgmt-doc/doc/install.html .